# HTML5 form attributes with Django forms and django-bootstrap-toolkit

Tags: django, html, twitter-bootstrap, django-1.5, django-crispy-forms

In a `Django 1.5` Application with `django-bootstrap-toolkit`, I want to have the following html result:

```
<div class="input-append">
    <input class="span2" type="number" id="offer_finance_vat" min="0" max="99" value="20">
    <span class="add-on">%</span>
</div>
```

Important are the appending "%" as well as `type="number"`, `min` and `max`

Here is my Form code:

```
class FinanceForm(forms.Form):

    vat = forms.DecimalField(
        decimal_places=0,
        label="Value added tax",
        widget=BootstrapTextInput(append="%"),
        initial=0,
        min_value=0,
        max_value=99
    )
```

But in html `type`, `min` and `max` are missing then.

Is there also an opportunity to get a `step="2"` attribute?

Would this be possible with `crispy-forms`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the value of the [widget.attrs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget.attrs) to pass certain other HTML attributes to the form.

```
>>> from django import forms
>>> name = forms.TextInput(attrs={'size': 10, 'title': 'Your name',})
>>> name.render('name', 'A name')
u'<input title="Your name" type="text" name="name" value="A name" size="10" />'
```

-Django Docs

Comment: yes, this works! but not really DRY (i have to put min/max twice). Is there a better solution?

Comment: I am not as familiar with the Bootstrap Django toolkit. Do you have to put in that `max` and `min` separate from the `widget.attrs` ?